# Help to implement an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

How can I implement this summation in *Mathematica*, where $r$, $k$ and $n$ are fixed value:

```
r=3;
k=0;
n=0;
```

[image]

Edit: Is that right?

```
Sum[
 Sum[
  If[l != m,
   Product[
    If[And[q != l, q != m], (r - k - q)], {q, 0, r}]], {l, 0, r}]/
      Product[
        If[l != m, (m - l)], {l, 0, r}], {m, n + 1, r}]
```

Comment: For example, how can I put the condition (l .neq. m) at the sum.
The same for (q .neq. l,m) at the product.

Comment: easiest might be to divide the product/sum to two parts, for the sum in the numerator, `Sum[...,{l,0,m-1}]+Sum[...{l,m+1,r}]`

Comment: Note:  You can use the function `If[l != m, ...]` to include only terms that obey your inequality constraint.  Also, if your question is for known fixed values of $r$, $k$, and $n$, then please put those in your equation, so we're not solving a more general (and more difficult) problem than necessary.

Comment: In fact my interest is solve the general form. I put those values because are the first of my analyze but my interest is in the general solver.

Comment: Your `If[]` statements are missing something. Hint: what do you get when you multiply something by 1? And, if you add 0 to something?

Comment: If I put:

`r=3,k=0,n=0`

I get:

`(Null + 3 Null^2)/(2 Null) - (Null + 6 Null^2)/(2 Null) + (
 Null + 11 Null^2)/(6 Null)`

Comment: The `Null` is because of the issue I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r = 3;
k = 0;
n = 0;
Sum[Sum[If[l == m, 0, Product[If[q!=l && q!=m, (r - k - q), 1], {q, 0, r}]], {l, 0, r}]/
 Product[If[l != m, m - l, 1], {l, 0, r}], {m, n + 1, r}]
```

> 1/3

Comment: Thanks @kglr! Problem solved.

Comment: @Mateus, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: @Mateus, you can also upvote (resp, downvote) answers and questions that you like (resp, dislike),  by clicking [the triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png)